# Customizing Android-Keyboard-Keys

Tags: android, keyboard, key, label

I'm looking for a possibility to customize my keyboard-keys. In the following picture you can see the result i'd like to reach:

[keyboard-key result](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/6307/buttontt.png)

Optional: When I multitap on a key, the keyPreview should step through the list of characters of this key (nice to have).

Problem:
If I use the label-attribute of a key, the text of the label only appears in the center of a key. But I need to put the <kbd>A</kbd> in the top-left-corner, the <kbd>B</kbd> to top-middle, etc.). I also tried the keyIcon-Attribute, but then the keyPreview showed only the **keyIcon**, and not each character, when I multi-tap on the button.

Currently I'm 'designing' my keyboard with `<Keyboard ..><Row ..><Key /></Row></Keyboard>`-XML, not with a LinearLayout or a similar layout. Maybe I need to switch to a LinearLayout?

Any ideas?